# calculate two arrays with each other javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to read out some values from the web page
of https://www.immobilienscout24.de/ and edit -> then display them in the console.

[image]

The values are also displayed in the console.

[image]

may be that the solution is simple, but I do not see it. That is why I need your help.

What I want to do:

```
Price per square meter = price / living space
Price per square meter = 74000/26
```

Value

```js
console.log(priceResult);
console.log(livingspaceResult);
```

[image]

Unfortunately I do not know how to marry the values?

```js
console.log(entry1);
console.log(entry1);
```

Can anyone help me?

```js
var crawlPrice = document.getElementsByClassName("font-nowrap");
var priceSearchstring = /\d+\.\d+/g;

var crawlLivingspace = document.getElementsByClassName("font-nowrap");
var livingspaceSearchstring = /(.*) m²/g;
var entry1;
var entry2;

for (var i = 0; i < crawlPrice.length; i++) {
  var priceResult = String(crawlPrice[i].innerHTML).match(priceSearchstring);
  var livingspaceResult = String(crawlLivingspace[i].innerHTML).match(
    livingspaceSearchstring
  );

  console.log(priceResult);
  console.log(livingspaceResult);

  if (!!priceResult) {
    priceResult.forEach(function (entry1) {
      console.log(entry1);
    });
  }

  if (!!livingspaceResult) {
    livingspaceResult.forEach(function (entry2) {
      console.log(entry2);
    });
  }

  crawlPrice[i].style.background = "yellow";
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the values of `priceResult` and `livingspaceResult` are

Comment: Those images are not accessible without logging into that forum. Your approach - selecting the prices and areas separately and then combining them - seems haphazard. What if the prices and areas don't perfectly line up? You should iterate through the cards that contain those values, and get the pairs of values from each card one by one. That would eliminate any need to combine the arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have adapted the posting. 
The pictures now have a different source. 

Also the values of the two array
console.log(priceResult);
console.log(livingspaceResult);
are now displayed in the image. 

I do not know how to calculate the two values with each other. 
I want to calculate price per square meter. 
Thanks for the help,